# Android Get data from rawQuery to another form

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want get `Id` from the cursor to the `EmployeeDetails` form,  but I get no result. This is my code:

```
public class EmployeeList extends ListActivity {
    protected EditText searchText;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);
    }
    public void search(View view) {
// || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM employee WHERE firstName=?", 
            new String[]{searchText.getText().toString()});
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmployeeDetails.class);
        long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the record values from cursor object you need to iterate it and retrieve the data from it...

```
if(c.getCount()>0){ if (c.moveToFirst()){  c.getLong(0); }}
```

where c is your cursor object... Also check whether cursor is not null...

Answer (score 0):

If firstName is String use firstName like 'XYZ'